# phoenix heex does not see a variable in a loop

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, heex

I'm new to Elixir and Phoenix, and I expect to get stuck, but this *really* surprises me. I'm fighting with the `heex` templating system. This is the part that I'm stuck at now:

```
<div id="issues">
  <%= for issue <- @issues do %>
    <.live_component module={ColifeWeb.IssueLive.IssueComponent} id={@issue.id} issue={@issue}  />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Elixir says: **`variable "issue" is unused (if the variable is not meant to be used, prefix it with an underscore)`**. But it's used! I can see it! It's used twice in fact! What's going on here? This can't be because it's used in an argument. That would make no sense.

Comment: `id={@issue.id}` → `id={issue.id}` it’s not an instance var.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I had forgotten about that. Thanks. I feel very silly.

Answer (score 2):

because issue is not an instance var, you could just write issue, or you can use :for inside tag e.g

```
<div id="issues" :for={issue <- @issues}>
    <.live_component module={ColifeWeb.IssueLive.IssueComponent} id={issue.id} issue={issue}  />
</div>
```